# Create command for a width

Tags: macros, width

How can I put this code into command to be more organized and precise?[image]

Comment: Looks quite disciplined to me. Do you want the whole thing become a macro with lengths as arguments while keeping the rest same?

Comment: fine with me. I want to use the `\documentclass{exam}` to be able to use the `\question` command for the proper numbering. I just make use for `\documentclass{article}` for the sample code. Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a columntype for that:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabu,longtable}
\newcounter{myrow}
\newcommand\mybox{\fbox{X}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\stepcounter{myrow}\themyrow.}l
X[3]
@{\hspace{2em}}
>{\mybox}l
@{\hspace{4pt}}
X}


\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth{Y}
&
sometext
&&
some long text some long text some long text some long text 
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of using `&` to number the text, can i use the `\question` command by the `\documentclass{exam}`to have a proper number order? And instead of writing && can i just use a name variable like `\option` to be more precise? But how will I define it based on the answer you have given me?

Comment: yes you could use the \myquestion that you showed in the question to avoid typing the & explicitly I didn't do that as you didn't provide a usable example to bas on (a screen image of code is not as useful as a complete runnable document) You probably don't want to use `\question` as it will not be designed to be used in a table but you could use the question counter instead of `myrow` I just used that as that was what you had used.

Comment: Should I merge my code with your answer? When I tried to replace `&` to `\myquestion` it no longer compiles.

Comment: myquestion is _your_ definition it takes two arguments and makes a whole row of the table.

Comment: I replaced `&` with the `\myquestion` command but it do give me errors. I inserted the `\newcolumntype` in my file but it did not compile.

Comment: This is what i wrote: 
      `\begin{document}

      \begin{longtabu} to \textwidth{Y}
      \myquestion{Here's the text for the first question;  and we add some text to apan more than one line.}{choice1}  \      \myquestion{Here's the text for the second question; and we add some text to apan more than one line; and we add some text to apan more than one line; and we add some text to apan more than one line.}{choice2}  \     \end{longtabu}

     \end{document}`

Comment: should probably work if it doesn't please edit the question to include a complete runnable document that shows the problem